# filter for pronoun, verb, PlaceName in swift 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, string

For example:

The algorithm is currently able to filter this sentence

> What is the weather in San Francisco?

to this

`What: Pronoun
is: Verb
the: Determiner
weather: Noun
in: Preposition
San Francisco: PlaceName`

The Code I wrote is in **Swift 3** and uses the **NSLinguisticTagger** API. Unfortunately there's not much of a documentation for this specific API.

```
let question = "What is the weather in San Francisco?"
let options: NSLinguisticTagger.Options = [.omitWhitespace, .omitPunctuation, .joinNames]
let schemes = NSLinguisticTagger.availableTagSchemes(forLanguage: "en")
let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: schemes, options: Int(options.rawValue))
tagger.string = question
tagger.enumerateTags(in: NSMakeRange(0, (question as NSString).length), scheme: NSLinguisticTagSchemeNameTypeOrLexicalClass, options: options) { (tag, tokenRange, _, _) in
    let token = (question as NSString).substring(with: tokenRange)
    print("\(token): \(tag)")
}



var range = NSRange()
var oldString: String = "Where in the world is Carmen San Diego?"
var newString = (oldString as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: oldString) as? NSString


var tokenRanges: NSArray?
let tags =  newString?.linguisticTags(
    in: NSMakeRange(0, (question as NSString).length),
    scheme: NSLinguisticTagSchemeNameTypeOrLexicalClass,
    options: options, orthography: nil, tokenRanges: &tokenRanges
)
```

Now I would like to **filter** for *Nouns, Verbs and PlaceNames* in order to later perform for in this example weather API request.

> is, weather, San Francisco

Comment: That's not filtering, that's classification.

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is your desired outcome?

Comment: updated the question ;)

Comment: Can you make me a playground that compiles?

Comment: yeah that code is from my playground

Comment: What's the purpose of the whole bottom half of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you're asking for:

```
import Foundation

struct TaggedToken {
    let token: String
    let tag: String
}

let question = "What is the weather in San Francisco?"
let options: NSLinguisticTagger.Options = [.omitWhitespace, .omitPunctuation, .joinNames]
let schemes = NSLinguisticTagger.availableTagSchemes(forLanguage: "en")
let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: schemes, options: Int(options.rawValue))
tagger.string = question

var nounsVerbsAndPlaceNames = [TaggedToken]()
tagger.enumerateTags(in: NSMakeRange(0, (question as NSString).length), scheme: NSLinguisticTagSchemeNameTypeOrLexicalClass, options: options) { (tag, tokenRange, _, _) in
    let token = (question as NSString).substring(with: tokenRange)
    print("\(token): \(tag)")

    switch tag {
    case "Noun",
         "Verb",
         "PlaceName": nounsVerbsAndPlaceNames.append(TaggedToken(token: token, tag: tag))
    default: break;
    }
}

print(nounsVerbsAndPlaceNames)
```

Comment: Thats awesome thanks. May I ask how you found the answer?

Comment: You already had everything you needed. You already print *all* tags, so it's just a matter of using `if` or `switch` statements to only keep those that you want. I made a struct to pair together `tokens` and `tags`, because I anticipate it will come in handy. Using a tuple of `(String, String)` would've worked too.

Comment: is there a way to just print: is, weather, San Francisco? (sorry for bothering)

Comment: @iag Either: swap out my `TaggedToken` array with an array of just `String`, and add to it just the tokens - or - just use map: `nounsVerbsAndPlaceNames.map{ $0.token }`